# Can the MM algorithm be applied to a constrained optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

I was reading Professor Kenneth Lange's book: Optimization and there is a whole chapter dedicated to the MM algorithm but from what I was seeing. All of the example were applied for non-constrained optimization problem only ?

Is it possible to applied it for constrained problem ?

For example:

$\begin{array}{l}
Min\,\,Z =  - xy - 2x\\
st\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,xy \le 12
\end{array}$

Where $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. MM "can deal gracefully with equality and inequality constraints". There are many examples of applying MM to constrained optimization problems in

[Examples of MM Algorithms, Kenneth Lange, de Leeuw Seminar, April 26, 2018](http://hua-zhou.github.io/teaching/biostatm280-2018spring/slides/20-mm/deLeeuw.pdf)

Comment: I am sorry I was unable to understand the document. Could you provide a concrete example of constrained optimization with the MM algorithm ?

Comment: I have no examples to give you beyond what it is in that link. If it is too complicated to understand, you will never succeed doing it yourself, and are better off using an existing constrained optimization solver, of which there are many.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Please consider avoiding absolute statements like "you will never succeed" or the like, as they add little to your answer and only help in demotivating the OP (let us let them decide what they are capable of, or not). Best,